# CSP nonce ignored by Safari

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

So I implemented CSP for my web app and it works perfectly fine in Chrome. All inline scripts with `nonce` are executed; and the ones without it are not executed.

In Safari however, this is the message I see in the console:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src'
>   contains an invalid source:
>   ''nonce-fbe23fb21d40c38e8df7c0a16357dd3ec4be86ca233cb41206ac5f897cf9a103''.
>   It will be ignored.

Header:

```
Content-Security-Policy script-src 'nonce-cb28e5c8a2b833169bb8d1fa686f659fed9b3bf8ea52b86916bcaf20a04b3209' 'self'
```

None of the inline scripts are executed , even the ones with nonce.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Safari does not yet support nonces (please bug your local webkit representative to support this) but Firefox and Chrome have implemented the standard behavior which is backwards compatible. Namely, if a nonce is present then `'unsafe-inline'` is ignored.

Send both `'unsafe-inline'` and your nonce and you will get the desired behavior. Safari will complain about the "unknown source value" but it will work as intended.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#directive-script-src

Comment: I have no idea but if ng-click doesn't work with CSP, that's ng-click's problem, not CSPs.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that unsafe-inline should be avoided where possible, because it defeats the purpose of using CSP in the first place.

Comment: @nucc1 It does if you use it *without the nonce* but the standard says to ignore 'unsafe-inline' if you have nonces or hashes in your script-src, so in this case it's fine.